# Using a pipe inside a bash function

Tags: bash

Is there a way I can make this one liner here into a bash function?

```
mdfind -name autoflush.py | grep -Ev 'Library|VMWare|symf|larav' | sort
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
function mdf () { mdfind -name "$1" | grep -Ev 'Library|VMWare|symf|larav' | sort }
```

but didn't have success with it.

Can't I use the pipe operator inside functions in bash?

My next approach was this:

```
function mdf () {
    result=mdfind -name "$1"
    grepped_result=grep -Ev 'Library|VMWare|symf|larav' $result
    sort $grepped_result   # return sort $grepped_result ?
}
```

I am guessing there are many conceptional errors in my approach. So I would appreciate any help and input.

Comment: There are three problems with your second attempt: when assigning output from a command to a variable, you need to use `$( )` to capture the output. For example, `result=$(mdfind -name "$1")`. Second, `grep` and `sort` take file*names* as arguments, not data; you'd have to use `echo` and pipe its output to the command. Third, you almost always need to double-quote variable references to prevent word-splitting and wildcard expansion (e.g. `echo "$result"` instead of `echo $result`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon in the first attempt.

```
mdf() { mdfind -name "$1" | grep -Ev 'Library|VMWare|symf|larav' | sort; }
```

Just a quirk of shell syntax that you need it there. If you put the command on its own line then you don't need one.

```
mdf() {
    mdfind -name "$1" | grep -Ev 'Library|VMWare|symf|larav' | sort
}
```

(I've removed the `function` keyword. For compatibility's sake you should write either `func()` or `function func` but not combine them.)

Give [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) a try the next time you're stuck. It's a syntax checker for shell scripts. A real godsend.